# How to use Material-UI with .Net Core MVC CSHTML Project?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, material-ui

I want to use material-UI within a dot net core MVC project which uses CSHTML. I don't want to use React which is mainly used with material-UI. So, is there any way to include MUI into the .Net MVC project? I especially want to use the RTL language support from MUI library -> [Material-UI RTL Support](https://mui.com/material-ui/guides/right-to-left/).

If its possible, then how & where to include the library?
Is there any package dependency we need to install?

Thanks in advance.